# Encrypt Roundcube password in config.php

Tags: php, password-encryption, roundcube

I have a roundcube setup however in the config.php, the database connection is formatted as mysql://username:password@localhost/Database_name

This password is in plain text which is obviously never a good idea, how can I make it encrypted? You'd think this would be standard

Answer (score 0):

Block access in your .htaccess

```
<files config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: This is present in the config subfolder blocking all access to the folder.. is this secure enough?

Comment: do you mean there is code like this in your .htaccess file that blocks access to the entire folder? or there is another .htaccess file within that folder with the line `Deny from all`?

Comment: In the config folder, so that ./config is off limits where the file is stored, for some reason I feel this isn't secure enough?